# install mysqldb for python

Tags: python, windows, mysql-python

i try to install mysqldb for python, i'm new to python, sorry before.
when i typed "python setup.py install" on my prompt, this is the msg :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\Python26\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_key'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

i am using python 2.6, mysq-python 1.2.3, running on 7 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Install MySQL-python from source can be tricky on Windows.
Use an exe installer or use ActivePython + Pypm

This is a good place to get binary package of many python libraries

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Windows MSI installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.msi/download) now on SourceForge. Try that, but if you'd rather build your own, for now (until 1.2.4 is released), you should be able to do this:

```
pip install http://svn.code.sf.net/p/mysql-python/svn/branches/MySQLdb-1.2/MySQLdb
```

The above assumes you have Subversion installed. Also you need the appropriate [C connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) installed. Then review the settings in site.cfg.